"Error opening input" error when running ffmpeg via shell script
I'm on a macbook running sonoma 14.7.
I have the following ffmpeg command which runs just fine by itself in the same folder of the files I need to modify:
ffmpeg -i "water-stream-90fps.mp4" -vf "drawtext=text='Frame\: %{frame_num}': start_number=1: x=(w-text_w): y=(h-text_h):fontsize=(h*10/100):fontcolor=yellow,drawtext=text='%{pts\:hms}':x=0:y=0:fontsize=(h*10/100):fontcolor=yellow" "water-stream-90fps-with-markers.mp4"
However, when I try to use it in a shell script by running ./add_markers.sh in the same folder, I get an error.
This is the add_markers.sh script:
#!/bin/bash

# Replace '/path/to/your/folder' with the actual path to your folder
folder=$(pwd)

# Replace 'ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=640:480 output.mp4' with your desired FFmpeg command
ffmpeg_command="ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf \"drawtext=text='Frame\: %{frame_num}': start_number=1: x=(w-text_w): y=(h-text_h):fontsize=(h*10/100):fontcolor=yellow,drawtext=text='%{pts\:hms}':x=0:y=0:fontsize=(h*10/100):fontcolor=yellow\" output.mp4"

echo "$ffmpeg_command"

# Loop through all files in the folder and execute the FFmpeg command

for file in "$folder"/*; do
    filename=$(basename "${file%.*}") #get only the first part of the file name without path or extension

    # Replace 'input.mp4' with the current filename and 'output.mp4' with the new filename. 
    # Added double quotes to manage filenames with spaces.
    new_command="${ffmpeg_command//input.mp4/\"$filename.mp4\"}"
    new_command="${new_command//output.mp4/\"$filename-with-markers.mp4\"}"

    echo "Running $new_command"

    $new_command

done

This is the error I get (for one of the files, same error for all of them):
Running ffmpeg -i "water-stream-90fps.mp4" -vf "drawtext=text='Frame\: %{frame_num}': start_number=1: x=(w-text_w): y=(h-text_h):fontsize=(h*10/100):fontcolor=yellow,drawtext=text='%{pts\:hms}':x=0:y=0:fontsize=(h*10/100):fontcolor=yellow" "water-stream-90fps-with-markers.mp4"
ffmpeg version 7.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/7.0 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags='-Wl,-ld_classic' --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenvino --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-audiotoolbox --enable-neon
  libavutil      59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
  libavcodec     61.  3.100 / 61.  3.100
  libavformat    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavdevice    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavfilter    10.  1.100 / 10.  1.100
  libswscale      8.  1.100 /  8.  1.100
  libswresample   5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libpostproc    58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100
[in#0 @ 0x6000015bc300] Error opening input: No such file or directory
Error opening input file "water-stream-90fps.mp4".
Error opening input files: No such file or directory

I tried all kinds of things but my brain is starting to swell. Any guidance/help would be appreciated.
